# Ctrl+z key does not work when logged in as UserA, but works when logged in as UserB in Aseprite application

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde

This is very strange occurrence I am trying to figure out. I installed Aseprite (A popular pixel editor) on my regular UserA account on Kubuntu/KDE. However the CTRL+somekey e.g. Ctrl+z, Ctrl+C or Ctrl+x and others will not work. I have to use the menus for those functions. The Ctrl key by itself is a function for selecting layers in Aseprite. I can reassign the the Meta key to those functions and works fine. But If I log in as UserB and start Aseprite the Ctrl+somekey works fine! Aseprite is installed using a .deb download.

I tried to figure it out by making sure the .bashrc and .profile and also the keyboard preferences for Aseprite are the same in both accounts. It seems when I am logged in as UserA it ignores the key pressed while holding down Ctrl.

So why would it not work under UserA but work under UserB? An tips on debugging it? They have a free trial version if anyone wants to try it https://aseprite.org/trial/  or https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite